# Customising UITableViewCell with many UILabels

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

Basically, I want to have four labels on my contentview. I customised the UITableViewCell in IB, with my own custom class. I wanted the labels to be stacked one after another.

However the labels seems to be on top of the others, which makes the other labels not visible. I have the following configuration:

```
title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
title.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
title.numberOfLines = 0;
```

[image]

For all of my labels. I also made sure I have the correct height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method (which is just adding the height of all the labels). I'm not sure where I went wrong... Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Picture of the UITableViewCell for those who are interested:
[image]

Comment: From the picture above I can tell that your current UITableViewCell has hight of 24 px. That is not enough to stack 4 UILabels on top of each other, unless they are very small. Can you put a picture of your cell from IB?

Comment: @Cyrpian, that is the inspector for the labels (one of the labels is 24 px). I'll post the cell nevertheless. (If it helps, the second label covers the third and fourth. The top one is ok)

Comment: So is only one of the labels showing up?

Comment: What happens when you turn the vertical stretch autosizing off?

Comment: @BojanG everything will be displayed, but when one of the labels has more than one line, it won't display the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems problem of autoresizing. Did you try to set autoresizing for all the labels? Also the picture you have posted in the question in that picture origin anchor I can see in center while it should be in top left corner.

Comment: I did set autoresizing for all labels. I think the problem is I don't know how to say "after resizing, let the space between labels stay the same". I thought I did that by ticking the lines outside the inner box...

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it turns out I needed to increase the height of some labels in IB. Do you know why this is the case? I thought auto resizing in height will take care of that? After I increased the height in IB, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check by changing this:

```
title.numberOfLines = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried that before. I forgot to mention that the labels may be given content that's bigger than one line.